# Powershell Read Sharepoint List Item of Type FieldUserValue[]

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

The SharePoint list has a column with 1 to 3 names in it. Its type is **FieldUserValue[]**.
I get the field type from this:

**$FieldType = $Item[$Field.InternalName].GetType().name**

```
 ForEach($ColumnName in $ListRow) {

     $ColumnName.LookupValue
                            # This yields "Robert Green" --only one name in this row/column       
                            # This yields "FieldUserValue[]" when multiple names in this row/column
 }
```

I have tried for days to get the names from this column. Does anyone know how to retrieve such data using Powershell?

How the data appears in the Sharepoint List:

## ColumnName

Robert Green

## ColumnName

Bill Grey

Amanda Reyes

Molly Mandala

Comment: Try `foreach($name in $ColumnName.LookupValue) {$name}` or perhaps `$ColumnName.LookupValue -join ', '` to get a comma delimited list if that suits you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample script to read multiple user field value.

```
$userValueCollection = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue[]]$item["Employee_x0020_Name"]

    foreach ($FieldUserValue in $userValueCollection)
    {
         write-host $FieldUserValue.LookupValue.ToString()
    }
```